# How to prevent one element from triggering scrolling

Tags: html, css

I frequently have a "background" decoration that I want to display if it fits on the screen but I don't want to trigger scrolling. It appears that I have the option only to 1. Use `overflow: hidden` and prevent any child from enabling scrolling or 2. allow it to scroll the page.

Is there a way to avoid a particular child from triggering scrolling?

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  
  // If enabled, the long word doesn't trigger scrolling.
  // If disabled the header decoration does.
  //overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1::before, h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 -100vw;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some fancy Header</h1>
<p>Some text withaverylongwordinitthatshouldalwaysbevisible.</p>
```

Comment: you could make the background it's own div inside the body that has `overflow: hidden` and make it `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` inside the body with `height: 100vh`?

Comment: I don't think that works because I then need a way to align the decoration with the header while it is not a child element.

Comment: Could you please provide the full html and css code? A js snippet would be preferred also.

Comment: There is an example in the question. No js is involved (ideally)